# MobileNetv1 - High and Fluctuating validation metrics

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, keras, tensorflow, metric

i've been using the MobileNetv1 model, pre-trained on ImageNet in Keras. I replaced the last layer with my own softmax layer to classify my images into one of 10 classes (maybe too few for such model and makes it overfit?)

During training, I froze the first 47 layers of the model.
The final results are overall good, the confusion matrix is pretty promising and the evaluation shows a 0.95 accuracy, despite having a 1.25 loss.

The questions I would like to get help on are the following:

1. Why is the validation loss so high despite the accuracy being so good?
2. Why is validation loss fluctuating so much during training, is it potentially due to overfitting?

[image]

[image]

Comment: How many images per class are you using for training and validation?

Comment: 100 in validation for each class, between 2000 and 3000 in training, could it be a Unrepresentative Validation Dataset
As described here? https://machinelearningmastery.com/learning-curves-for-diagnosing-machine-learning-model-performance/

Comment: That is a reasonable explanation.